# Node.js HTTP: request 'end' event is never called

Tags: http, node.js

I have a client that is sending data chunks to my node.js server.

I want to listen on the "end" event and retrieve the accumulated request body.

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res){

  req.on('end', function() { // WHY IS THIS NEVER FIRED?
    console.log(req.body);

    res.send({
      "status": "ok"
    });

  });

});
```

The problem is that the 'end' event is never fired.

Anyone knows why?

Also, if I do in this way, will the req.body be the accumulated body of all the body chunks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically http POST only fires when you POST to the server.  I can't be certain, but I'm assuming you are just attempting to visit `server:port/users` in your web browser and fail to get a response.  By default the web browser is `GET`ing the server.  To fix this you have two options.

**1.** If you change `app.post` to `app.get` the event will correctly fire when you visit `/users`

**2.**  Or you can fire the post function using a form.  For example the following code will display a form if you visit the page using `GET`.  When you submit the form it will fire `POST`.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

app.get('/users',function(req,res){
  res.send('<form method="post" action="/users"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>');
})

app.post('/users', function(req, res){
  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('success');
    res.send('success!!!');
  });
});
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding. The client is firing a POST request. The POST handler is run, the issue is that the 'end' event is not fired and I have no idea why.

Comment: Works for me, try reinstalling node.js. I took my best guess for the situation.  The 1st code you posted also works for me provided I properly POST to the page.  Could you please do some more diagnostics.

Comment: i am having this same problem - the code used to work forever and now after some upgrades it stopped working

Comment: Why did you mark it as the answer if this didn't work? If I had to venture a guess it'd be that the req stream is paused and you need to use `req.on('data', savethechunks)` to unpause it (you will need to save the chunks manually I'd assume)

Comment: @ajsie Chris T is correct: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_compatibility_with_older_node_js_versions

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, and found this discussion helpful:
[My http.createserver in node.js doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363439/my-http-createserver-in-node-js-doesnt-work)

Simply put, by inserting the line:
`request.on("data",function() {})`
inside the `.createServer` loop but after the `request.on` loop made it work.

Comment: For anyone looking for more info on why this is, see here (specifically the bit about flowing and paused mode): https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable