# My http.createserver in node.js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello guys i just started learning node.js today and search a lot off stuff on the internet , then try to code in node.js i use these two codes to show me the same result but the last one is show the error on my browser something likes "can not find the page".So please explain to me why?

```
// JScript source code
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This is working but

```
// Include http module.
var http = require("http");

// Create the server. Function passed as parameter is called on every request made.
// request variable holds all request parameters
// response variable allows you to do anything with response sent to the client.
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Attach listener on end event.
   // This event is called when client sent all data and is waiting for response.
   request.on("end", function () {
      // Write headers to the response.
      // 200 is HTTP status code (this one means success)
      // Second parameter holds header fields in object
      // We are sending plain text, so Content-Type should be text/plain
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      // Send data and end response.
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

This one is not working

Why?

The link of the last one that's not working
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/
Thank you for all the answers, but i still don't understand about the problems.
the last one that is not working just has request.on?

Comment: I'm guessing your "end" event on the request isn't firing yet.  I'm not actually sure there is an "end" event on `request`... IIRC the callback function isn't even executed until the request is received...

Comment: @Joe There's an "end" event on request, but it's only relevant when POST or PUT data needs to be streamed. The event listener is executed when the request headers have been received in full, but before the request body has been received.

Comment: " the last one that is not working just has request.on?" - Sarin, if you can't accept that every single line or character or placement of parentheses can have drastic influences in the working of your code, you won't come far in any programming language.

Comment: No i'm not good in english as you can see. so i want to make sure that i cam made you guys understand my question by make the word as clear as i can.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`request` is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage`, which implements the `stream.Readable` interface.

Documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end says:

> #### Event: 'end'
>
> This event fires when no more data will be provided.
>
> Note that the end event will not fire unless the data is completely consumed. This can be done by switching into flowing mode, or by calling `read()` repeatedly until you get to the end.
>
> ```
> var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
> readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
>   console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
> })
> readable.on('end', function() {
>   console.log('there will be no more data.');
> });
> ```

So in your case, because you don't use either `read()` or subscribe to the `data` event, the `end` event will never fire.

Adding

```
 request.on("data",function() {}) // a noop
```

within the event listener would probably make the code work.

Note that using the request object as a stream is only necessary for when the HTTP request has a body. E.g. for PUT and POST requests. Otherwise you can consider the request to have finished already, and just send out the data.

If the code your posting is taken literally from some other site, it may be that this code example was based on Node 0.8. In Node 0.10, there have been changes in how streams work.

From http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/

> WARNING: If you never add a 'data' event handler, or call resume(), then it'll sit in a paused state forever and never emit 'end'.
> So the code you posted would have worked on Node 0.8.x, but does not in Node 0.10.x.

Comment: I appriciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The function you are applying to the HTTP server is the [`requestListener`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) which supplies two arguments, `request`, and `response`, which are respectively instances of [`http.IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

The class `http.IncomingMessage` inherits the `end` event from the underlying readable stream. The readable stream is not in flowing mode, so the end event never fires, therefore causing the response to never be written. Since the response is already writable when the request handler is run, you can just directly write the response.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen();
```

Comment: "The class `http.ServerResponse` does not have an end event," - indeed, but he's subscribing to the `end` event of the `request` object, which is an `http.IncomingMessage`. See my answer for details.